# replace string with data from database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to replace certain text with data in the database using php eacht time i type a text between this <% and %>. It doesnt have to be this character, i just made this up.

```
$text='This <%125,150%> is a fine product';
```

125 is the p_id and 150 is the size of the image.

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|  p_id  | name   |  img   |
+--------+--------+--------+
|   125  |  Shoe  | h.jpg  |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

The output has to be this:

```
This <img src="/h.jpg" width="150" alt="Shoe"> is a fine product.
```

I think a need to detect the <%125,150%> and extract the 2 values and use this in a function to connect with the MYSQL database to get the values.

Comment: why you don't want to use functions and variables? like getProducts($fromid,$toid)

Comment: because the people who are going to use this don't know coding. They just write a text in simple html and want to put some products-images between the text.

Comment: I think the easiest way to accomplish this is a frontend js framework like Angularjs that loads the data. then you can use handle bars to extract data in html